# How to create a category path from database on php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a database shown below. I need to create a path of category from subcategory.

Eg: Website shows that,  parent > Child > Child > Child

```
SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id;
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

When I choose "7 | MP3 PLAYERS" I want to display like below.

ELECTRONICS > PORTABLE ELECTRONICS > MP3 PLAYERS

Which technique i am used here?

Comment: Fetch data using recursive function.

Comment: How to use recursive function

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. By Recursive function it is possible.

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

  if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
    $user_tree_array = array();

  $sql = "SELECT `category_id`, `name`, `parent` FROM `category` WHERE 1 AND `parent` = $parent ORDER BY cid ASC";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
      $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row->category_id, "name" => $spacing . $row->name);
      $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->category_id, $spacing . '---', $user_tree_array);
    }
  }
  return $user_tree_array;
}

$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
?>
<select>
<?php foreach($categoryList as $cl) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: If you face any problem then let me know.. ;)